# Option is not showing results from my database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display product categories from my database, but the option are just blank, The database is connected as I get no error messages at all, so I was just wondering if anyone could give me some assistance. I have tried to change my variable with the database text but still does not work.

Image of Phpmyadmin

[image: Image of Phpmyadmin]

```
<?php 
// db.php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Marcus","*****","electronicshub",);
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error())
    }
?>
```

```php
<?php
    include("includes/db.php")
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Insert Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-337.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awsome\css\font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->
    <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
        <ol class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->
            <li class="active"><!-- active Begin -->
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard / Insert Products
            </li><!-- active Finished --> 
        </ol><!-- breadcrumb Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row Finished -->
<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->
    <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->
        <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- panel panel-default Begin -->
            <div class="panel-heading"><!-- panel-heading Begin -->
                <h3 class="panel-title"><!-- panel-title Begin -->
                    <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Insert Product
                </h3><!-- panel-title Finished -->
            </div><!-- panel-heading Finished -->
            <div class="panel-body"><!-- panel-body Begin -->
                <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- form-horizontal Begin -->
                    <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Title</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
                            <input name="product_title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                        </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
                    </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
                    <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Category</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->
                            <select name="product_cat" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->
                                <option>Select a Category Product</option>
                                <?php
                                    $get_p_cats ="SELECT * FROM product_categories";
                                    $run_p_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_p_cats);
                                    while ($row_p_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_p_cats)) {
                                        $p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_id'];
                                        $p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_title'];
                                        echo "
                                            <option value='$p_cat_id'> $p_cat_title</option>
                                        ";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select><!-- form-control Finished -->
                        </div><!-- col-md-6 Finished -->
                    </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
                </form><!-- form-horizontal Finished -->
            </div><!-- panel-body Finished -->
        </div><!-- panel panel-default Finished -->
    </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finished -->
</div><!-- row Finished -->


<script src="js/jquery-331.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-337.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check if the `$get_p_cats` query results in an error...

Comment: Your PHP contains syntax errors. It would be a miracle for your codes to run properly. You should enable `display_errors` to show errors and warnings. Btw, I wonder what is the content in your `db.php`; you have already included all the codes you need to connect DB in your PHP.

Comment: db.php is the code above I just put it all into one page, I have my display_errors on as they have worked in the past when their are errors but this case no errors have occurred.

Comment: @marcus I think your code must be `$p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['p_cat_id'];` not `$p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_id'];`

Comment: And $p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['p_cat_title'];

Comment: @VanTho I got rid of the $ and it is all working now, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @marcus You're welcome ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i found the error, you're using dollar with key name

```
$p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_id'];
$p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_title'];
```

**it should be like**

```
$p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['p_cat_id'];
$p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['p_cat_title'];
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code

```
$p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_id'];
$p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['$p_cat_title'];
```

you have used variable $p_cat_id instead of string 'p_cat_id' (Please note $ is not required) inside the row array variable

so the revised code would be

```
$p_cat_id=$row_p_cats['p_cat_id'];
$p_cat_title=$row_p_cats['p_cat_title'];
```

Comment: Your answer will be easier to read if you format the lines of code separately. In addition, this question already has an accepted answer and yours doesn't appear to add anything else to that answer or question.